# Using another model manager's code in a Django custom manager class

Tags: django, django-orm, django-managers

I have two models, say, `Question` and `Topic`.

I am trying to add methods to the Question model's custom manager, e.g. some method that filters by `Topic`.

I can't seem to use the other manager's code for this (cannot `import Topic` either, so I can't do `Topic.objects...`)

In `class QuestionManager`

```
def my_feed(self, user):
       topics = TopicManager().filter(user=user) # 1st approach
       #topics = Topic.objects.filter(user=user) # 2nd line
       # do something with topics
```

class TopicManager
     ....

Using 1st approach, I get the following error:

```
virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in get_meta(self)
    219         by subclasses.
    220         """
--> 221         return self.model._meta
    222 
    223     def clone(self, klass=None, memo=None, **kwargs):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I can't use the 2nd line since I can't import Topic, since Topic depends on the TopicManager in this file. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a manager directly, in any circumstance. You always access it via the model class.

If you can't import the model at the top of the file because of a circular dependency, you can simply import it inside the method.

Comment: What would be the performance hit of importing inside method? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place this at the bottom of the `managers.py` module:

```py
# Prevent circular import error between models.py and managers.py
from apps.drs import models
```

In your manager classes you can reference other models using `models.<modelname>`, and this should work, avoiding the circular import.

For example:

```py
class QuestionManager(Manager):

    def my_feed(self, user):
        topics = models.Topic.objects.filter(user=user)
        # do something with topics

# Prevent circular import error between models.py and managers.py
from apps.drs import models
```

This works because you are importing the module, not the model classes, which results in a lazy import. By the time the function is run the module will be imported and everything will work.

You could also load models by name using `django.apps.get_model()`:

```py
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_model('my_app', 'MyModel')
```

Details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model)

For example:

```py
from django.apps import apps

class QuestionManager(Manager):

    def my_feed(self, user):
        topics = apps.get_model('my_app', 'Topic').objects.filter(user=user)
        # do something with topics
```